# Guidelines for calling controller methods in helper modules?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, helper

Few questions:

1. Is it possible to call a controller method in a helper module (e.g., application helper)?
2. If so, how does the helper handle the rendering of views?  Ignore it?
3. In what instances would you want to call a controller method from a helper? Is it bad practice?
4. Do you have any sample code where you're calling controller methods in helper?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You generally don't call controller-methods from helpers. That is: if you mean a method that collects data and then renders a view (any other method that needs to be called should probably not be in a controller).
It is definitely bad practice and breaks [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

It is, however, perfectly possible to make controller-methods available in the views, a great example is for instance the `current_user` method.

To make a controller method available in the views, as a helper method, just do

```
private

def current_user
  # do something sensible here
  @current_user ||= session[:user] 
end
helper_method :current_user
```

Such a method is best defined in the `private` section, or it could be available as an action (if you a wildcard in your routing).

Answer (score 10):

Declare your methods on the corresponding controller

```
private
def method_name1
...
end

def method_name2
...
end
```

In the head of the controller declare

```
helper_method :method_name1, :method_name2
```

You may want to declare those methods under private state

And that's it, now you can use your method on a helper

Answer (score 0):

Calling a controller from a helper violates the MVC pattern. IMO if you need to call a controller from a Rails view helper (like `application_helper`) then there is something about the design that could be improved. The intention is that helpers "help" views, and therefore only talk to models.

I'm not going to defend MVC itself here (there are a  ton of references on the web), but this SO thread about calling the controller from a view should get you started.

[Calling controller from view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708015/calling-controller-from-view) (note, this is an ASP.NET thread, so only the high level principles are relevant).

Comment: the thread you linked is about ASP.NET so it may not be much help.

Comment: Oops.I could have sworn that I saw a relatively recent Rails question along those lines, but that obviously isn't it. I guess the point is that the view helper should really be seen as part of the view, and the MVC pattern frowns upon calling the controller from the view. Googling Rails MVC is an exercise left to the OP.